# use of - (oneway void) in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, oneway

Can anyone send me a sample code to write asynchronus method using "oneway" (oneway void) for iOS. So that it will not block the calling thread until the method returns.

Comment: `oneway` is only used in Distributed Objects, which are not available on iOS.

Comment: @Bavarious, you should add this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `-performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` method on `NSObject`. I also recommend Apples [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html) for some best practices when using asynchronous methods.